# Not able to store values in table

Tags: java, mysql

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;
```

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.text.Annotation;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.fasterxml.classmate.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student_Info obj = new Student_Info();
    obj.setName("hello1");
    obj.setRollno(4);


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    // this would save the Student_Info object into the database
    session.save(obj);


    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close(); 
}
```

}

Comment: Your question contains nothing but code, and that code isn't even properly formated. Please include at least a useful error description or we have absolutly no idea what your problem might be and what you ecpect us to do with that code snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you didn't map your Student_Info as expected, you need to use the tag @Entity, that way JPA understands that you want to persist this object.

@Entity
public class Student_Info {

}